# I have dual Colombia/US citizenship. Travel to Colombia

Tags: customs-and-immigration, paperwork, dual-nationality, colombian-citizens

I have dual Colombia/US citizenship. I need to do a short trip to Colombia in a week.I have both my US and Colombian passports, but I don't have a cedula.

I'm very worried that I'll have problems at immigration. I've emailed them and called the embassy and heard no response. Can anybody help me? Maybe I can take an additional document?

Comment: What do you mean by cedula? Colombian ID?

Comment: You'll be perfectly fine, see my answer

Comment: If you are required to have a cedula *in addition to your passport* then I don't see how an additional document would help.  I do not know whether such a requirement exists, however.

Comment: @phoog It doesn't

Answer (score 1):

A passport is **the** universal travel document - unless a country doesn't recognise the country issuing the passport, it has to be accepted as a travel document.

Plus, Colombia cannot refuse entry to you as a Colombian citizen - even an expired passport would be accepted.

So this is what you need:

1. At check-in for the flight to Colombia: Colombian passport
2. At Colombian entry immigration: Colombian passport
3. Check-in for flight to the US: US passport
4. Colombian exit immigration: Colombian passport
5. US immigration: US passport

Comment: But could the traveler be fined for failing to have her cedula?  Might she be forbidden from leaving Colombia without a cedula?

Comment: @phoog No, there is no such requirement. No country in the world requires this except Venezuela for naturalised citizens, who must have a passport **and** ID card **and** naturalisation papers.

Comment: How do you know that?  If the country requires its resident citizens to have an ID card, as Colombia apparently does, how do you know that this requirement won't be enforced on entry at the airport, and how do you know that it does not apply to citizens who reside abroad?

Comment: @phoog "As Colombia apparently does" According to whom? If it's the link I think you're referring to, its' clearly a mistranslation. Also Timatic makes **zero** mention of it, and it most certainly would if such a requirement was in place

Comment: According to Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Civil_Registry_(Colombia); https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_document#Colombia).  My Spanish isn't good enough to find anything to support or rebut that claim on Spanish government websites.  See also https://colombiareports.com/5-things-know-colombias-new-police-code/.  Timatic presumably cares only that a country will accept a traveler and not fine the airline.  They don't care if the traveler is fined for lacking some other document after being admitted to the country.

Comment: @phoog The Washington Colombian Embassy site states that both passport and national ID are required, so it looks like the OP will need to obtain a new cédula before travelling http://www.colombiaemb.org/node/1759

Comment: @Traveller That's exactly the link that I explained is a mistranslation.

Comment: @phoog "Timatic presumably cares only that a country will accept a traveler and not fine the airline." You are **completely wrong** here. Timatic doesn't "allow" boarding passengers who would be in violation of regulations and could be fined, **except** if actual practice at the airport differs from formal law (most commonly regarding document validity periods). Otherwise it would say US citizens can enter the US with any proof of nationality, for example, and it would rarely say that passports of the destination country have to be valid, rather than expired ones also being accepted

Comment: @phoog Also the first Wiki link doesn't say you need it to enter and Exit, while the second link provides no reference whatsoever

Comment: @Coke Do you have that link in Spanish? I’m assuming the OP would understand it, and I think my Spanish would be good enough too. Given the extent of the debate on this forum, surely the best solution is for the OP to apply for a replacement cédula?

Comment: My point is that it doesn't matter whatsoever whether the ID is required for entry and exit.  Suppose for example that it is *not,* but that Colombian citizens without the document are subject to a fine of $266 as noted in the colombiareports.com link.  In that is the case, the traveler *would* need the ID to avoid the fine, and your answer would be misleading.

Comment: Regarding your assertion about TIMATIC and the US, there is a US law requiring a valid passport, even if it is not enforceable in practice. But travelers transported to the US with contraband can be fined, yet airlines do not search travelers for contraband. Enforcement of domestic law is not the airlines' concern. Another example: Dutch nationals require a Dutch passport or ID card when they're in the Netherlands, even if they are citizens of another country, yet airlines do not check for this.

Comment: The webpage of the Colombian Consulate in Buenos Aires (‘nota’ section) states clearly that a dual national requires a passport to enter and leave Colombia. I can’t see any reference to a cédula in this regard http://buenosaires.consulado.gov.co/tramites_servicios/pasaportes However @phoog’s point about all Colombians needing to be able to produce their cédula if requested to do so seems valid to me - possibly this could occur on arrival eg if there were spot checks.

Comment: @Traveller Can't find a Spanish version, as the Spanish website version isn't identical (I checked the Spanish-language FAQ section and didn't find it)

Comment: @Traveller And as for in-country identification, I'm not making any statements, as this Q is about entering Colombia. I now called immigration at El Dorado airport who said that either a valid cédula or a valid or expired passport is required to enter, while to depart, a valid passport or cédula is needed.

Comment: Thank you guys sooo much! The wording on el conculados website is a bit tricky.. but your comments really put me at ease i thought i had to cancel my trip! Really appreciate it :)

Comment: @JulianaSarmiento If you do face any issues (which I cannot imagine happening) be sure to report!